# CiviCRM emails not sending with attachments

Tags: email

I'm sending post event emails to participants Find Participants> Event Name is> send mail to less than 50). These send fine when just mail body text is included.

When I add an attachment and press submit I get the following error message
[image]

I tried the same thing from find contacts- Find Contacts- random search criteria> send to less than 50.

Again, just text works fine, add an attachment and this time I get sent to the advanced search page with this message popping up

[image]

Currently Civi 5.19.4 Drup 7.69

Anyone seen anything similar?

Woo-hoo! Just recreated on dmaster.demo

[image]

Raised at lab.civicrm.org
https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1604

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attachment size exceeded the site max file upload.

Not a bug in Civi as suspected, but the error message is really unhelpful in this instance.